# Looking for an alternative to flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flex to align a text and two buttons inside a div. This is my code

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-right: 90px;
}
#left {
    padding-top: 33px;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
    flex: 0 0 65%;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 44px;
}
#right {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    flex: 1;
}
#button1 {
    height: 70px; 
    width: 70px; 
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#button2 {
    height: 70px; 
    width: 70px;
}
```

```html
    
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <input type="button" value="More" id="button1">
        <input type="button" value="Ok" id="button2">
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is working properly on most browser but in some others flex is not supported. Is there any other method that can I use to achieve the same result and create the banner?

Comment: use inline-block elements

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result using lot of techniques in css, i'll show you some examples:

`Using Inline-block element`
    https://codepen.io/joaoskr/pen/OaEdJz

`Using Float left`
    https://codepen.io/joaoskr/pen/JeZxXX

`Using table alignment`
    https://codepen.io/joaoskr/pen/zMaewv

As you can see, you have lots of possibility to achieve the same result without use flex, choose which you think better, hope it can help you !!

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the Inline-block element. The problem is that the top and bottom padding is not working on the buttons anymore, do you have an idea about the problem? this is the code https://codepen.io/kev34/pen/GwGeya

Comment: @pungis Add `float: left;` to the #left and #right element, then add this line

#wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a polyfill for the browsers that don't support flexbox. For example: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Modernizr has several options listed here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#flexible-box-layout-spec

That way you can still use flexbox and also support other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browser versions support flex, however you may want to include some browser specific rules for legacy support.

`-webkit-flex:` for Chrome 21.0+/Safari 6.1+

`-ms-flex:` for IE10

`-moz-flex:` for Firefox 18.0+