# Center a div without using flex

Tags: html, css, centering

I created a banner with a text and two buttons. I used Inline-block element to align the elements as I do not want to use flex. The left padding on the banner is set correctly but not the right one. I am enable to center the banner content (the #wrapper element) on the screen so that the padding on the left and on the right is equel to 90px. DO you have an idea about the problem? This is my code and this is a [demo](https://codepen.io/kev34/pen/GwGeya)

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: gray;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
}

#wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#left {
  padding-top: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
  width: 65%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 44px;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#button1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button2 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="button1">more</div>
    <div id="button2">ok</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you need another question, seems the same to this one :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478572/looking-for-an-alternative-to-flex .. you can edit the old or remove it, both have the same purpose

Comment: as a side note, you are not using inline-block here, you are using float ... inline-block is useless when you set float

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to float:left is set for element having id="right" in styles. Change float to right for #right as given below.

```
#right {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;    <!-- // Change left to right  -->
}
```

Comment: In this case the buttons exceeds the div on the right

Comment: now give some padding-right value like padding-right: 90px in #right {} block in styles

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the `width=100%` and in the `wrapper`, the padding will be set correctly:

```
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    /* width:100%; */
  height: 160px;
    background-color: gray;
    padding-left: 90px;
    padding-right: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [calc() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) , [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and the [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) like this

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: gray;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 480px; 
  width: 100%;
  max-width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#left,
#right{
display:inline-block;     
vertical-align: middle; 
 white-space: normal;
}

#left {
  padding-top: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
  width: calc(100% - 160px); /*160px = 70x2 + 20*/
  text-align:left;
  line-height: 44px; 
  background: orange
}

#right {
  width:160px;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#button1,
#button2{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px; 
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
#button1 { 
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

#button2 { 
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="button1">more</div>
    <div id="button2">ok</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center any `block` element (like a `div`) by giving it a definite `width` (70%, 350px) and setting the `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto`. The div should center just fine. Hope this helps.